# Spectrometer Experiment

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics

What happens if the results of observations(experiment) by the spectrometer on Helium light source spectrum there are only 3 colors (e.g yellow, green and blue), while the reference there are 5 colors (plus red and purple)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the source has not yet reached the proper temperature, so the other lines are still too dim for your spectrometer. Try waiting and use longer integration time.